# Adding line break within function string

Tags: php, string

I am pretty new to PHP.  How do you add a line break to the bit of fedex string in the following function?

```
tep_draw_textarea_field('comments', 'soft', '60', '5', 'Shipped via Fedex www.fedex.ca Tracking number:');
```

Here is how the function is defined:

```
function tep_draw_form($name, $action, $parameters = '', $method = 'post', $params = '')
```

Comment: Those are 2 different functions...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use double quotes and a "\n":

```
tep_draw_textarea_field('comments', 'soft', '60', '5', 
     "Shipped via Fedex www.fedex.ca Tracking number:\n");
```

Comment: Perfect thank you! what does using single quotes with a string mean besides not allowing for code like line breaks?

Comment: It is not parsed for variables and character substitutions like newline (\n) or tab (\t). This generally makes the code faster. However, if we want special characters as in this case, you need to use double-quotes. If you like my answer, could you please mark is as solution? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

A line break is represented by "\n";

The following code will insert a line break (note the double quotes):

```
tep_draw_textarea_field('comments', 'soft', '60', '5', "Shipped via Fedex www.fedex.ca\n Tracking number:");
```